# User responses feed shows "ToAtomFeedDate()" in date

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, responses, atom

The root of the [user responses feed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/84237/responses) returns:

```
<updated>4/21/2011 3:52:49 PM.ToAtomFeedDate()</updated>
```

The funny `ToAtomFeedDate()` is too difficult for my humble reader! It would rather see:

```
<updated>2011-04-21T15:52:49Z</updated>
```

(The other dates in the same feed are fine. The user feed itself is okay too. And so are question feeds, and I guess all others.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a razor view encoding error, fixed in the next build.